# Numeric=character varying :operator does not exist based on postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this :

```
Select office_name, ofc_code 
from table1 
where ofc_code in (select ofc_institution from table2 where id ='2')
```

If i run this i get an error:

```
Operator does not exist:numeric = character varying
Hint : no operator matches the given name and argument types
```

In the above query: `ofc_code` is numeric and `ofc_institution` is a character varying

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare apples to oranges. `'2'` is a string value, `2` is a number.

You also need to convert `ofc_institution` to a number if you are certain that it only contains numbers (the question then is: why on earth are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column?):

```
Select office_name, ofc_code 
from table1 
where ofc_code in (select ofc_institution::numeric
                   from table2 
                   where id = 2);
```

If you can't be certain that `ofc_institution` is always a number, then cast the `ofc_code` to a string - but that then begs the question why are you comparing those columns to begin with:

```
Select office_name, ofc_code 
from table1 
where ofc_code::varchar in (select ofc_institution
                            from table2 
                            where id = 2);
```

Comment: @StevieWeedyLyngdoh: see my edit. You seem to have a horrible table design if you are comparing apples with oranges

Comment: Yeah i know ..actually the query  was written by someone else...i came to fixed those errors... thats y im having a lots of errors  in those queries... and i have to do it..its my job... neway thank you for your help..really appreciate  it..thanks

Comment: Before _properly_ fixing the queries, please be sure to look at the table structure and understand, that relational databases are not dynamically typed. If you have a `psql` session, just do a `\d+ table1` and `\d+ table2` and look at the data types of columns `table1.ofc_code`, `table2.ofc_institution` and `table2.id`. That should make you understand what is wrong with this query and others.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ..yeah i got it..its solved ..thanks a lot once again.... 